# git rebase (if no conflicts) otherwise git merge

Tags: git, merge, rebase

When my branch has no conflicts with master, I prefer to do a `git rebase`, because it keeps a plain history.

But when there are conflicts, sometimes `rebase` makes me solve the conflicts for each remote commit, which is more work. Also, I consider that if there are conflicts then the probability that the conflict resolution introduces a new bug is higher, so in that case I prefer to do a `merge` instead, that keeps clear record of where I started coding, what I did, and how I resolved the conflict.

So I keep doing:

```
git fetch -> git rebase
```

And, if there is any conflict:

```
git rebase --abort
git merge
```

I find myself doing this several times per day. Is there any built-in way to achieve this? Or should I create a `git` alias?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to inspect the incoming commits manually, *then* decide on rebase-vs-merge, but you can in fact automate this, using the fact that `git rebase` will exit with a zero (success) status if it completes the rebase, and a nonzero (failure) status if it does not.  You can therefore write a tiny shell script, or one-line command suitable for use as a shell alias:

```
git fetch && { git rebase || { git rebase --abort && git merge; } }
```

which says to run `git fetch`, and if it succeeds, run the braced series of commands:

- `git rebase`, and if that succeeds, nothing else; or

  - `git rebase --abort`, and if that succeeds, `git merge`

(The inner braces are not actually required since `&&` binds more tightly than `||`, at least in sh and bash.  They are here more for clarity of intent.)